# Migration from GlassFish 3 to Payara 4 - Facing CDI enablement issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, overriding, payara

I am working on POC of migration of an application from GlassFish 3 to Payara 4. I have done the required configuration setup in Payara like jdbc connection pooling, queues, etc. There are EJB components in the application but it builds into a war file and deploys and run on GlassFish 3 server. But, when I try to deploy on Payara 4, CDI error is displayed as:

**Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI definition failure:HV000151: A method overriding another method must not alter the parameter constraint configuration....**

**Error StackTrace:**
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method overriding another method must not alter the parameter constraint configuration,...
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.rule.OverridingMethodMustNotAlterParameterConstraints.apply(OverridingMethodMustNotAlterParameterConstraints.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.assertCorrectnessOfConfiguration(ExecutableMetaData.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.build(ExecutableMetaData.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataImpl$BuilderDelegate.build(BeanMetaDataImpl.java:677)

Since CDI enablement is the new feature added in Payara, so there must be some configuration changes required while migrating application from lower version of GF to Payara which seems to be tricky to understand. So is there any way to actually deploy this war file on Payara?

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying your WAR with Implicit CDI disabled

- in Admin Console, uncheck the option **Implicit CDI** when deploying your application
- when deploying from console, add property `implicitCdiEnabled=false`, e.g. `asadmin deploy --properties=implicitCdiEnabled=false myapp.war`

If you're deploying from an IDE or don't want to disable implicit CDI on each deployment, you can try adding `beans.xml` file into your app's WEB-INF folder with the configuration that sets `bean-discovery-mode` to `none`, see: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-adv001.htm

Explanation: In Payara 4 and Java EE 7, there's a new feature called implicit bean discovery. That means if a JAR/WAR file doesn't contain the `beans.xml` file, some classes are automatically turned into CDI beans. If you application doesn't use CDI or uses a library that doesn't work with CDI this sometimes causes troubles.

Comment: I had deployed the war file from Admin console and uncheck the option Implicit CDI but still facing the same issue. Since I want to enable implicit CDI, I have set bean-discovery-mode to none in beans.xml file and I didn't face this issue. But then, I am getting an exception of Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton Object. In server logs, I have found that Null Pointer exception is thrown for the Ejb object been referenced in the Singleton class. So I guess now EJBs Objects are not getting initiated after the beans.xml is modified.

Comment: It seems that the original error with `OverridingMethodMustNotAlterParameterConstraints` is coming from a bean validation and not from CDI. Can you find the part of your code that causes the exception? The stacktrace says that your code overrides a method that has bean validation constraints on its parameters and modifies the constraints in the overriden method, which isn't allowed. The stacktrace doesn't say which part of your code does it.

Comment: I cannot share the original code. But, the dummy scenario goes as follows: There is an EJB interface having method like -- public String save(String input); It's implementation class overrides the method having parameter constraints for its formal arguments like -- public String save(@NotNull String input); Now this works in GlassFish3 but Payara throws the mentioned error. I have tried in both ways with/without constraints in that case I don't get this error. Since there are many ejb modules so I don't want to change any code instead I want to handle it at configuration level.

Comment: It seems that the Bean Validation specification added a constraint on placing validations in subtypes: http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-methodlevelconstraints-inheritance. This isn't in place in GlassFish 3 but is applied in GlassFish 4 and Payara 4 as well as any Java EE 7 server. I think you can't migrate to Payara 4 without code changes - you need to move the constrains from the implementations to their interfaces.